# How Select specific merge columns from excel sheet using ole db c#

Tags: c#, excel, select, oledb, select-query

I want to get the red highlight RowColumn.
First column is made of single cell A4 and next is made of  merge cells
`[BCDE4],[FGHI4],[JKLM4],[NOPQ4],[RSTU4],[VWXY4]`

```
 ("select * from ["+sheetname+"$A4:V4]", MyConnection);
```

Table goes here:
[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. OLEDB will return the underlying cells, so your data is in B4, F4, J4 etc despite how it appears on the screen.